# iTunes apps with web code?

Tags: html, itunes, itunes-app

Recently I've started working on a website that is targeted at mobile web-browsers(iOS, 3DS, DSi, Android, etc). I would like to make an app on iTunes to go with this website. Problem is, I have *no* idea where to start or if it's even possible with my particular coding knowledge.

Can I write iTunes apps with HTML, CSS, PHP, etc., or do you have to know more complicated types of code? And if I can do it with web-code, do I need some kind of license to publish to the app store? How does this all work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about using a server backend to deliver content from PHP to a user client written in HTML/Javascript, this is very easy to do using iOS. You can use UIWebKit to display HTML and execute Javascript code. If you want cross-language support between Obj-C and JS, Objective-C can talk to Javascript using:

> [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)];

for Javascript talking to Objective C, this can be accomplished using delegates (specifically UIWebViewDelegate) which is detailed [here](http://blog.techno-barje.fr//post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write iOS apps (I believe this is what you mean by iTunes) in PHP.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for that link, Exactly what I needed! Do you know if you **have** to enroll in the "iOS Developer Program" to do it? Or does that just make it easier?